# refresh the page after countdown finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I have this countdown code:

```js
!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):a(jQuery)}(function(a){"use strict";function b(a){if(a instanceof Date)return a;if(String(a).match(g))return String(a).match(/^[0-9]*$/)&&(a=Number(a)),new Date(a);throw new Error("Couldn't cast `"+a+"` to a date object.")}function c(a){return function(b){var c=b.match(/%(-|!)?[A-Z]{1}(:[^;]+;)?/gi);if(c)for(var e=0,f=c.length;f>e;++e){var g=c[e].match(/%(-|!)?([a-zA-Z]{1})(:[^;]+;)?/),i=new RegExp(g[0]),j=g[1]||"",k=g[3]||"",l=null;g=g[2],h.hasOwnProperty(g)&&(l=h[g],l=Number(a[l])),null!==l&&("!"===j&&(l=d(k,l)),""===j&&10>l&&(l="0"+l.toString()),b=b.replace(i,l.toString()))}return b=b.replace(/%%/,"%")}}function d(a,b){var c="s",d="";return a&&(a=a.replace(/(:|;|\s)/gi,"").split(/\,/),1===a.length?c=a[0]:(d=a[0],c=a[1])),1===Math.abs(b)?d:c}var e=100,f=[],g=[];g.push(/^[0-9]*$/.source),g.push(/([0-9]{1,2}\/){2}[0-9]{4}( [0-9]{1,2}(:[0-9]{2}){2})?/.source),g.push(/[0-9]{4}(\/[0-9]{1,2}){2}( [0-9]{1,2}(:[0-9]{2}){2})?/.source),g=new RegExp(g.join("|"));var h={Y:"years",m:"months",w:"weeks",d:"days",D:"totalDays",H:"hours",M:"minutes",S:"seconds"},i=function(b,c,d){this.el=b,this.$el=a(b),this.interval=null,this.offset={},this.setFinalDate(c),this.instanceNumber=f.length,f.push(this),this.$el.data("countdown-instance",this.instanceNumber),d&&(this.$el.on("update.countdown",d),this.$el.on("stoped.countdown",d),this.$el.on("finish.countdown",d)),this.start()};a.extend(i.prototype,{start:function(){if(null!==this.interval)throw new Error("Countdown is already running!");var a=this;this.update(),this.interval=setInterval(function(){a.update.call(a)},e)},stop:function(){clearInterval(this.interval),this.interval=null,this.dispatchEvent("stoped")},pause:function(){this.stop.call(this)},resume:function(){this.start.call(this)},remove:function(){this.stop(),delete f[this.instanceNumber]},setFinalDate:function(a){this.finalDate=b(a)},update:function(){return 0===this.$el.closest("html").length?(this.remove(),void 0):(this.totalSecsLeft=this.finalDate.valueOf()-(new Date).valueOf(),this.totalSecsLeft=Math.ceil(this.totalSecsLeft/1e3),this.totalSecsLeft=this.totalSecsLeft<0?0:this.totalSecsLeft,this.offset={seconds:this.totalSecsLeft%60,minutes:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60)%60,hours:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60/60)%24,days:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60/60/24)%7,totalDays:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60/60/24),weeks:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60/60/24/7),months:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60/60/24/30),years:Math.floor(this.totalSecsLeft/60/60/24/365)},0===this.totalSecsLeft?(this.stop(),this.dispatchEvent("finish")):this.dispatchEvent("update"),void 0)},dispatchEvent:function(b){var d=a.Event(b+".countdown");d.finalDate=this.finalDate,d.offset=a.extend({},this.offset),d.strftime=c(this.offset),this.$el.trigger(d)}}),a.fn.countdown=function(){var b=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0);return this.each(function(){var c=a(this).data("countdown-instance");if(void 0!==c){var d=f[c],e=b[0];i.prototype.hasOwnProperty(e)?d[e].apply(d,b.slice(1)):null===String(e).match(/^[$A-Z_][0-9A-Z_$]*$/i)?d.setFinalDate.call(d,e):a.error("Method %s does not exist on jQuery.countdown".replace(/\%s/gi,e))}else new i(this,b[0],b[1])})}});




$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#countdown').countdown('2017/09/29 21:20:01', function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D:%H:%M:%S'));
  });                             
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clr"></div>
<div id="countdown"></div>
<div class="clr"></div>
```

I want to refresh the page when countdown is finished.

This is the most important part of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#countdown').countdown('2017/09/29 21:20:01', function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('%D:%H:%M:%S'));
  });                             
});
```

Comment: Is it just me or you posted empty jsfiddle example?

Comment: the code sorry : https://jsfiddle.net/200e10b2/53bcwL2r/

Comment: @ElChupacabra sorry this is correct file :  jsfiddle.net/200e10b2/53bcwL2r

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: Show us what you already tried. We won't do your work for you.

Comment: There seems to be several countdown libraries, which one are you using?

Comment: @Daerik i dont used any plugin all the code i posted in jsfiddle.net/200e10b2/53bcwL2r

Comment: Please don't post code at 3rd party sites and then link to them. Those links can become dead over time. Instead, just post your code right here in a code snippet.

Comment: @voloshin i dont have experience in javascript thats the code of countdown just i need to refrech the page after finished i have experience in php not javascript

Comment: @Jeert Look like you are using `The Final Countdown` - http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

Comment: @Scott Marcus okay you have a solution ??

Comment: @Daerik yes this what i used i draft the link plugin thanks man can you help me now ??

Comment: No, I don't. That's why I didn't post an answer. But, posting quality questions is something that all of us at SO strive to get. Helping new users understand how to create quality questions is one way.

Comment: @Scott Marcus oki thank you

Comment: @Jeert I would also suggest looking up CDN links for snippets. It will keep your code clean.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('#clock').countdown('2017/09/29 21:20:01', {
    elapse: true
}).on('update.countdown', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (event.elapsed) {
        location.reload()
    } else {
        $this.html(event.strftime('To end: <span>%H:%M:%S</span>'));
    }
});
```

See [this URL](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples/count-up.html) for examples.

**Edit** for Scott Marcus:
It is harder to meet that criteria in this case since OP doesn't have any broken code to correct (they just need all the code written for them). That being said...

The problem is that we need somewhere to place the page refresh code: `location.reload()` and the solution (as outlined in the library documentation) is to use the update.countdown function to fire code after time elapsed.

**Edit** for OP:
I have also positioned the `location.reload()` code in my answer to make this easier to understand.

Comment: A good answer should include an explanation of the problem and an explanation of the answer. Not just, "Try this code".

Comment: i want to load page when contdown stoped i dont want to start count after finhed

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. A question that just asks for the code to be written, should not be answered. That just encourages more similar questions.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I somewhat agree with you but the way to go about promoting this is by commenting on the original question or suggesting removal of it and not by discussing the relevance of the question in the comment portion of my answer.

I up-voted your initial suggestion because you were right (and I edited my answer to reflect), but I do not agree that my answer shouldn't exist or isn't helpful to others if that is your suggestion.

Comment: I’m sorry that you disagree. But, you will find that answers that shouldn’t have been presented in the first place will get down voted as well as the question. It is done as a deterrent, so that these types of questions don’t get rewarded with answers. As a somewhat new user on SO, you may want to understand and adopt the best practices used on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to go read up on their `event` [documentation](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#events). The event that you are looking for is `finish`, since you want to refresh the page once the countdown is complete. For further reading, I would suggesting reading up on jQuery's event handler attachment [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Basically, `The Final Countdown` triggers the event `finish.countdown` once it's complete so that jQuery can listen for the event and handle it properly. For DOM on-event handlers, I would suggest reading up on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Variable Defaults */
    var countDownTo = new Date().setSeconds(new Date().getSeconds() + 5);
    
    /* Init Countdown Plugin */
    $('#countdown').countdown(countDownTo, function(event) {
        /* Output String */
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%D:%H:%M:%S'));
    }).on('finish.countdown', function() {
        /* Refresh Page on Load */
        console.log('location.reload()');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: I like this answer better as finish.countdown was designed specifically for OP's purpose (to fire code at the end of the countdown).